# How to ensure Maven dependencies have expected source version?

Tags: maven, version-control

I am trying to build multiple Maven libraries out of the same source control.  I do not have a strong business need for versioning as the only requirement I have is simply that when a library or application is built, all the in-house Maven libraries it relies on are using the same source version.

I am using `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to obtain the source version as `${buildNumber}` in Maven.  However it is illegal to append this to the Maven `version` coordinate (which would have solved my problem).  I am wondering if there is another way to expose this in a Maven project then check it in a client (i.e. dependee) project.

Comment: So, you want to identify the maven version of an artifact with the source control's version number for that source?  If so, I don't see why you can't just set the version on the pom to what you want when you check it in . . . i.e. you could make the pom's maven version say '1' for the first revision in source, and so on . . .

Comment: That sounds like a requirement for versioning to me.  You want to be able to choose a "version" of the source code to use for all the libraries.  Versions don't have to be big official things.

Comment: With the same source control you mean the same location in the source control? If you like having several libs sounds like a multi-module build in Maven?

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky per my post it is illegal to append the source version I am obtaining via `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to the Maven `version` coordinate.

Comment: @khmarbaise same Git hash, per post they are being built out of the same scm.

Comment: @djechlin I'm not suggesting appending the source version.  I'm suggesting tagging the code in your version control system and using it as a Maven dependency.